# Why are the prime ideals of $R_f$ exactly the prime ideals of $R$ not containing $f$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, localization

Let $R$ be a ring and $D_f=\{\text{primes ideals in } R \text{ not containing } f\}$ be a basic open set. Let $R_f$ be the localization of $R$ at $f$, I am trying to show that $D_f=\operatorname{Spec}R_f$. I can see every prime in $D_f$ certainly gives a prime ideal of $R_f$, but how can I show the other direction?

Comment: For any prime ideal $P$ in $R_f$, its inverse image under the canonical map $R \to R_f$ is again a prime ideal. Show that this can not contain $f$.

Comment: @Rushy that looks like an answer to me - would you care to record it below?

Comment: @Kreiser done, I wasn't sure whether a comment was more appropriate since there was still some work left to do

Comment: @Rushy Just to make it clear, does the "=" in $D_f=Spec R_f$ sort of mean there is a one-to-one correspondence rather than saying they are equal? Because a prime ideal in $R_f$ is not directly a prime ideal in $R$.

Comment: The first, they are not directly equal, but isomorphic.

Answer (score 3):

For any prime ideal $P$ in $R_f$, its inverse image under the canonical map $R \to R_f$ is again a prime ideal. Show that this can not contain $f$.